# Pascal Length + round?

Tags: pascal, rounding

Hello I have a task I have no idea how it works.

I have to make a program in pascal in which you write a word, then the program finds the middle letter in the word and brings it out on a screen.
Example: you have the word "dog", the program will show on the screen the letter o, if there are  4 letters like "tree" then the program will go to mid and + 1, so it brings our the letter "e".
As I understand I need to use the function round(x) and Length(x) but I dont know how to use them right and how to define the VAR?

```
uses crt;
var 
  x,x1: string;
  z,y: real;
  y1: integer;
BEGIN
  readln(x);
  z:=length(x);
  y:= z / 2;
  y1:= round(y) +1;
  writeln;
  x1:=copy(x, y1,1);
  writeln(x1);
  readkey;
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

You use integers to index strings, not `real`s.

```
var
  Len, Mid: Integer;
  TestString: string;
  CenterChar: Char;
begin
  TestString := 'tree';
  Len := Length(TestString);
  Mid := Len div 2;

  // Your choice here
  if not Odd(Len) then
    Inc(Mid);

  // or you can use this instead
  {
  if (Len mod 2 = 0) then
    Inc(Mid);
  }

  CenterChar := TestString[Mid];   // Access string by index. No copy needed
  WriteLn(CenterChar);
end;
```